# Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ homeomorphics to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology

I am working on the paper of R. D. Anderson about the simplicity of some homeomorphism groups, and wanted to show it for the sets of rationnals, irrationals and the Cantor set. During my developpement i'm blocked into this :

"A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ (in the induced topology) iff it's countably infinite and has no isolated points"

The proof is well complicated and can't really understand it, does someone has a more 'easily undestandable' proof or can simply make it more clear?

Thanks

Comment: Note that this implies $\Bbb Q\cap [0,1]\cong \Bbb  Q\cap (0,1)$, for example.

Comment: Yes i can see it ! well actually i wanted to proove that all the non-empty proper open and closed subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are homeomorphic to each others, i could see that an open and closed set of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a countably infinite set with no isolated points, and just consider the restriction of the homeomorphism on those subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link on topology atlas](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.htm) has three different proofs, of varying degrees of complexity (it all depends on what you already know). I would check it out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, i love the back-and-forth method demonstration, i think its really clear now ! (i've had a look into some Sierpinski's theorem proofs, but as i am actually working without metric, the set theoritical proof was all what i found and it was a little bit hard to understand...)